# How to find preferences on MacBook

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, macbook

I am trying to help someone with Wifi problems who uses a MacBook. I don't have any experience with Apple products. This is the first time I have used an Apple product.

On the internet many refer to settings using a path like /Library/Preference.

It is unclear to me what this is. I am using the Finder which seems to be an app to find many many things but not applications, preferences and settings.

Is it possible to edit / change preferences when using a MacBook? I think it is a closed product right? It just works and if it doesn't work you just buy a new one I think.

Is it possible to start a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to any folder on the Mac if you have its text description like in your post.

- Switch to Finder.
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>   to open a new Finder window,
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>   for Go
- Copy/paste your path...

Note there is a difference between
`/Library/Preferences` & `~/Library/Preferences`
The tilde ~ means that is the individual user's folder, rather than the main system folder.
If you're used to Windows, I suppose you could think of `~/` as equivalent to `%USERPROFILE%\`

Almost all preferences files will open in TextEdit, but just because you can access a prefs file doesn't mean it will be in plaintext or easily recognisable XML form. It may be in binary or just not straightforward to figure out.
Sometimes it's simpler to trash a prefs file then just launch the app to rebuild it at defaults.

Basically, Mac is nix..*ish*, so if you know nix you can figure out Mac. Terminal behaves in a similar way on both, though they're not absolutely identical.
What it is definitely not like is Windows.
No Registry, no hives, no broken OS if you trash a prefs file you shouldn't - things relating to that pref will simply default.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do most things on the command-line on a Mac, it is primarily a GUI-based operating system and there is a special GUI for system preferences called, surprisingly enough, System Preferences.

The easiest way to access it is by clicking the "System Preferences..." under the Apple menu item in the upper-left corner. Alternately, you can launch it with Spotlight, which is launched by pressing:

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>

Type `system preferences` within the popup textfield and press return to launch the app.

Once you have System Preferences launched, click on the "Network" icon and you should see the Wi-Fi icon, which you can further drill into.